# How do I print a string based on the length given as input?

Tags: python, string, split

What I want to achieve is:

*Suppose the length that the user inputs is 6. Then the string that is to be input should also be of length 6 **(without having any whitespaces in between the characters)**.*

My code:

```
length=int(input())

S=input().split(" ",length)   # This works, but I have to provide spaces in between.
```

My expected input should be like:

```
>>>6
   abcdef
```

If I run the code above, then the input is like:

```
>>>6
   a b c d e f
```

Comment: Try `S=input()[:length]`

Comment: Are you generating the is the string randomly or getting it from the user using `input`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alternative 1:

If the string needs to be user input, the following might work:

```
length=int(input())
S=input()[:length]
print(S)
```

Alternative 2:

Assuming the string generated needs to be random, One way of doing this is by using two modules namely:

- random
- string

Code Looks as follows:

```
import random
import string

#Function to generate string
    
def get_random_string(length):
    letters = string.ascii_lowercase
    result_str = ''.join(random.choice(letters) for i in range(length))
    print("Random string of length", length, "is:", result_str)

#Calling the function to generate string of desired range:     

get_random_string(6)
```

The Output then is as follows:

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MO12n.png)